# Using ready() function to set elements to display but $(this) won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.share-button').ready(function(){
  $(this).css("display","inline");
});
```

I set all of my social media share buttons in a wrapper with `display:none` then I want to set them to display after they load. I am trying to use this function but it won't work. What do you think could be wrong?

Edit: My problem is that each button has to load an outside script so they are usually continuing to load after the page loads and their loading kind of glitches and things are resizing making it look weird. I need to do the function for each individual element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set them after the page load inside a DOM ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.share-button').css("display","inline");
});
```

API: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: My problem is that each button has to load an outside script so they are usually continuing to load after the page loads and their loading kind of glitches and things are resizing making it look weird. I need to do the function for each individual element.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this after `DOM` fully loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.share-button').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.share-button').css("display","inline");
});
```

documentation says $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

and this

```
$(function() {//this format is same as document.ready
    $('.share-button').css("display","inline");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just insert javascript tag after those .share-button and insert you code:

```
$('.share-button').css("display","inline");
```